# Creating Variables Based Off A String

Tags: python, string, variables, python-3.x

I have a string that reads `"blah blah @~@ blah blah @~@ blah blah @~@"`

How could I make it so that it creates a variable(string) for each `'@~@'` that feature in the string?

In this example I would end up with three variables - split1, split2 and split3

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: `string.split('@~@')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
str = "blah blah @~@ blah blah @~@ blah blah @~@";
split = str.split('@~@');
```

then you can access the individual values as:

```
print(split[0],split[1],split[2])
```

Output:

```
'blah blah ' ' blah blah ' ' blah blah '
```

Comment: A loop to print it out would be better.

Comment: This works great! I've used .split before and don't know why it just flew over my head! Is it it possible I could get it to add 1 to an integer for every '@~@' it reads in the string?

Answer (score 0):

As Joao said, and you also suggested in your question. You can use str.split to create a list of names. Rather than creating variable names based on these it is much more "pythonic" to create a dictionary based on these. i.e.

```
str = "name1 @~@ name2 @~@ name3";

x = str.split('@~@');

print x



d = dict((x[n],0) for n in xrange(0, len(x), 1))

print d
```

You could use `exec` but I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: This won't work in python 3. You need parenthesis in the call to `print`.